# TinyMCE styleselect with content_css using @import url()

Tags: css, tinymce

I'm using the latest version (3.4.3.1) of TinyMCE and am trying something that doesn't seem to work as expected.

I have specified a `content_css` which points to a file that `@import url();`'s another CSS file (the CMS and website are separated). This works fine for styling the content inside the editor. However, when using the `styleselect` function I can not get it to list the classes that are specified inside the imported CSS file.

When I add some bogus class definition it still doesn't work. When I exclude the `@import url();` line from the `content_css` file and keep the bogus class definition the class definition is available in the styles list.

I'd really like it if it would list the class definitions from the imported file. Because the CMS is separated from the website I'd like to keep all stylesheets stored at the website. The only stylesheet that *might* exist is the one that `content_css` points to. If it doesn't exist it's not being specified. These 2 points are the reason I `@import url();` a external stylesheet.

Comment: gosh! I have a hard time understanding. Is your question how to disable the content css from loading?

Comment: Thought it was a pretty clear question myself, but English isn't my native language so... I modified the question, hope it's more clear now. I want the content css to load, which it already does. It however doesn't list the classes that are specified in files that are included with `@import url();`. This `@import url();` call is inside the `content_css` file.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me. +1, I have no idea though because I avoid `@import` always.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that perhaps TinyMCE perhaps only loads the css file and parses it, not looking at `@import url();` calls. But I'm not sure about this.